# Replacing fields with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, siblings

Why is line 10 returning null?

http://pastie.org/720484

it works with line 40

Comment: Checkbox does not have siblings on Line 10

Answer (score 2):

You do not seem to have a proper grasp of the siblings() operator.  You also were not utilizing jQuery's val() function and were missing periods on some of your class names. To locate the address1 class you would need to do the following:

```
var $checkbox = jQuery(this); 
$checkbox.parent().siblings('.formField').find('.address1');
```

Also, you would want the alert to be

```
alert($checkbox.parent().siblings('.formField').find('.address1').val());
```

to alert the value of the input box.

**FIXED AND OPTIMIZED VERSION:**

```
function update_address(eventObject) { 
  var $checkbox = jQuery(this);
  var $siblings = $checkbox.parent().siblings('.formField');
  if ($checkbox.attr('checked')) { 
      $siblings.find('.address1').val($('.hidden_address1').val());
      $siblings.find('.address2').val($('.hidden_address2').val());
      $siblings.find('.city').val($('.hidden_city').val());
      $siblings.find('.state').val($('.hidden_state').val());
      $siblings.find('.zip').val($('.hidden_zip').val());
      $siblings.find('.province').val($('.hidden_province').val());
      $siblings.find('.country').val($('.hidden_country').val());
  } else { 
      $siblings.find('.address1').val('');
      $siblings.find('.address2').val('');
      $siblings.find('.city').val('');
      $siblings.find('.state').val('');
      $siblings.find('.zip').val('');
      $siblings.find('.province').val('');
      $siblings.find('.country').val('');
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try fetching the input:text's `.val()` instead

Comment: A good idea, yes, but doesn't have anything to do with why the siblings() function doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

On line 9, shouldn't it be `var checkbox = $(this);` instead? I've not seen the jQuery() function used like that.

Comment: Might be using jQuery in `noConflict` mode, more here: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: you do know that $ == jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

Because `<input class="address1"/>` is not a sibling of `<input id="parent_sameAsBefore"/>`. I think you want:

```
checkbox.parent().parent().find('.address1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just go with finding the form fields using absolute path?
Unless your DOM is very convoluted (and you need relative paths), I would prefer this approach myself.

Also use .val() to get and set values.

```
function update_address(eventObject) { 
  if($(this).attr('checked')) { 
    $('#parent_address1').val($('hidden_address1').val()); 
    $('#parent_address2').val($('hidden_address2').val()); 
    $('#parent_city').val($('hidden_city').val()); 
    $('#parent_state').val($('hidden_state').val()); 
    $('#parent_zip').val($('hidden_zip').val()); 
    $('#parent_province').val($('hidden_province').val()); 
    $('#parent_country').val($('hidden_country').val()); 
  }    
  else { 
    $('#parent_address1').val("");  
    $('#parent_address2').val("");  
    $('#parent_city').val("");  
    $('#parent_state').val("");  
    $('#parent_zip').val("");  
    $('#parent_province').val("");  
    $('#parent_country').val("");  
  }    
}
```

Note, seems to be a bug in the original code in line 15:

```
checkbox.siblings('.tate').value = $('hidden_state').value;
```

Should be:

```
checkbox.siblings('.state').value = $('hidden_state').value;
```

Comment: If noConflict mode is in effect, just replace $ with jQuery in above code

Comment: That would be better, but the error is the missing 's' in state :)

Comment: I don't think `o1.val() = o2.val()` will change o1. Afaik, and looking at the JQuery website, the new value should be a parameter, like so: `checkbox.siblings('.state').val($('hidden_state').val())`

Answer (score -1):

alert(checkbox.siblings('.address1').html() ); // This should be

alert(checkbox.parent().siblings('.address1').html() );

//Checkbox does not have siblings
Line 10

Comment: `<input/>` elements are supposed to be empty. In HTML, you don't have to explicitly close them, but in XHTML you need to "self-close" them. i.e. `<input/>`

Comment: @J-P: Thanks for the observation. He is trying to get the siblings of checkbox. He will get null cause checkbox has no siblings.